# enzyme "containsMatchingElement" and missing PropTypes in test code

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme

I have two correlated components:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Parent = () => (
  <div>
    <Son message1="this is required" message2="this too" />
  </div>
);

const Son = ({ message1, message2 }) => (
  <p>{message1}</p>
);

Son.propTypes = {
  message1: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  message2: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

I want to write a test using jest/enzyme for the `<Parent />` component similar to the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('<Parent />', () => {
  it('contains a <Son />', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Parent />);
    expect(
      // Son only has a subset of the properties! The ones I wanna check
      wrapper.containsMatchingElement(<Son message1="this is required" />))
    .toBe(true);
  });
});
```

The **test passes** but I get the annoying PropTypes warnings caused by creating the `<Son />` without all the necessary properties -- in the test code:

```
      Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `message2` is marked as 
required in `Son`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

I know I could use

```
expect(wrapper.find(Son).length).toBe(1)
```

...but it would not allow me to check if some of the properties match.

What is the best course of action in this scenario? I would like to have the test pass, and to skip/suppress the `PropTypes` warning.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Why do you not use snapshots: http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/snapshot-testing.html#content

Comment: Also why is `message2 required` if is never used?

Comment: Hi, regarding message2, this is just an artificial test to showcase the issue. Snapshot testing is also something I use, but I wanted to find out if there's a way to also use `containsMatchingElement` in a productive way.

Comment: I wonder if  [dive()](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.md) will help here? It allows you to shallow render a child non-dom element.

Answer (score 2):

You've set both props as required, so unfortunately even to create an object for matching purposes you will need to provide both props to the Son element or else you will see those warning messages.

However, if you ONLY need to check that one Prop, you can write the test slightly differently:

```
expect(wrapper.find(Son)).toHaveLength(1); // Should be exactly 1 Son element
expect(wrapper.find(Son).props().message1).toEqual("this is required");
```